# Pure Qt application (QML/QtQuick) on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have a Qt application that is based on QML/QtQuick and runs, among other platforms, on Android. Is it possible to compile this application without (major) modifications for Ubuntu phone? If yes, how?

I know that Ubuntu phone applications use QML/QtQuick too, but I do not want to add any Ubuntu-specific code because the original intention of a portable Qt application is to use the same code on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what you're using. If your app uses any Android-specific APIs for things like notifications or background services, then you'll need to replace those with something that works on Ubuntu.

Also, if you are using QtQuick.Controls components, you'll either need to replace them with equivalent Ubuntu.Components or include the QtQuick.Controls package in your app's package, as I don't think we include that as part of the base install.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that QtQuick.Controls are included.